# What is the right parameter for SqlPackage.exe to publish a .dacpac file that can drop the absent objects on target database?

Tags: synchronization, command-line-arguments, database-project, sql-server-data-tools, sqlpackage

As we can use `SqlPackage.exe` from Microsoft SSDT in Visual Studio 2012 to sync database as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20322688/248616), I'm using it to sync target database, called `TargetDb`, to match with the source database objects stored in an SQL Server Database project, called `DbProject`.

The action `/a:Publish` of `SqlPackage.exe` command allows us to sync the DbProject's .dacpac file to TargetDb but the default arguments **will NOT drop TargetDb's objects which not exist in DbProject**.

Turning on the flag `/p:DropObjectsNotInSource=true` will solve this but also creates weird behaviors

1. The flag `/p:DropObjectsNotInSource=true` will drop the user/login objects on TargetDb which is absolutely not expected! The closest ones I can find is `/p:DropRoleMembersNotInSource=false /p:DropPermissionsNotInSource=false` but those do not help much.
2. The flag `/p:DropObjectsNotInSource=true` will break the flag `/p:BlockOnPossibleDataLoss=true` which means if data-loss occurs, the update action(s) will not be blocked; that is NOT what I want at all.

Currently I have to accept 'trash'/redundant objects on TargetDb :(

What are better flags to use to get me there?

Comment: #1 - I think there's an option you can pass to ignore users/permissions. I've got those set in my advanced publish profile to avoid affecting users. It seems to work.
#2 - Haven't hit this yet. Have you tried generating a custom script to get you started or using pre-deploy scripts to avoid some of the issues around potential data loss?

Comment: @PeterSchott @1 What is that option you are using in your profile?

Comment: <DropPermissionsNotInSource>False</DropPermissionsNotInSource>
    <DropRoleMembersNotInSource>False</DropRoleMembersNotInSource>
    <DropObjectsNotInSource>True</DropObjectsNotInSource>

Comment: The arguments seem the same as my command-line's ones. I will try to use profile and back with you later

Answer (score 1):

I asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17402904/prevent-dropping-of-users-when-publishing-a-dacpac-using-sqlpackage-exe) and ended up scripting the users as a post-deploy script to recreate them after deploying the database upgrade.

The `DropPermissionsNotInSource` property only applies to `GRANT` / `DENY` permissions.
`DropRoleMembersNotInSource` is just for role membership.

Sadly there isn't an option to exclude users from the objects being dropped when the `DropObjectsNotInSource` property is set to true.

We also make certain changes (like changing column types) in pre-deploy scripts, as `BlockOnPossibleDataLoss` can prevent deployment even when the change won't cause data loss. I guess it's good it's over cautious rather than not cautious enough.

Answer (score 1):

You should try using the `/p:DoNotDropObjectType` parameter which would allow you to specify which type you want to drop that is not in the source i.e. when `DropObjectsNotInSource` is true

Answer (score 1):

Use `ExcludeObjectTypes` to ignore the users/logins.

```
/p:DropObjectsNotInSource=true /p:ExcludeObjectTypes=Users;Logins;RoleMembership;Permissions;Credentials;DatabaseScopedCredentials
```

`/p:BlockOnPossibleDataLoss=true` has no effect when `/p:DropObjectsNotInSource=true`, so don't bother ticking that off.

Comment: If you want to exclude just one type, it's /p:ExcludeObjectType=Users

Answer (score 1):

while the answer from @Ε Г И І И О accomplishes the objective, there is a more specific solution to the DROP scenario:

One issue when using /p:ExcludeObjectTypes is the object types get excluded from the whole deployment, including CREATE and ALTER statements, and these might be needed in some cases.

[Microsoft details on the sqlpackage properties DropObjectsNotInSource and DoNotDropObjectTypes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage/sqlpackage-script?view=sql-server-ver16#properties-specific-to-the-script-action)

the /p:DoNotDropObjectTypes property can only be set when used together with /p:DropObjectsNotInSource, this way we are only restricting/excluding the object types from the DROP statement, but we are not affecting CREATE and ALTER.

Both ways work, but if you need CREATE and ALTER then it is better to use /p:DoNotDropObjectTypes

**Edit** 2024-03-15: with our team we have reviewed this topic, and we think there is a better approach, but we would need Microsoft to include new properties for sqlpackage.exe [new properties IncludeObjectTypes, DropObjectsTypesNotInSourceList](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/278354c9-efe2-ee11-a73d-0022484c4e0d). If you like the idea an upvote in the Microsoft URL would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please be aware that that "prevent data loss" could has also to be set in the project file:

[image]

Comment: This only applies when you debug. I think what OP wants to do is run SqlPackage.exe manually with switches.